# Using Internal Storage for Android App install after external storage

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have an app which currently allows to be installed into external storage. The app is developed using Xamarin in Visual Studio. I would like to start using Android App Bundles for deployment, but there is limitation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/release-notes/9/9.4#initial-support-for-android-app-bundle-publishing-format) that app has to have "internalOnly" attribute for the installation.

Question: If users of my app have the app already installed to external storage, and they got an update that requires internal storage for installation, what will happen?

Comment: Basically speaking,the  app couldn't been installed in external storage(Sd card) ,at least not without rooting.The main reasons is Android does not allow you to install an application to your external SD card because of `Security` and `Volatile storage`.And  today's mobile phones are basically without SDcard .

Comment: I'm not complaining about removing this feature in general, what I would like to understand what will happen with users who already had app installed on external storage.

Comment: I'm sorry that I haven't found device with SDcard to testing.Have you tried it?

Comment: I have old device with SD card, but didn't try it yet. Got distructed. I might try it later, then will answer my question.

Comment: @maxim facing exact same situation, may I ask you what did you do in the end?